# Multiple Line Scala List

Tags: scala, list, split, user-defined-functions

When I input a single array into my function, I get the correct result.  Now, instead, I would like to feed into my function a multiple line List (or some other Type that I can make from a multiple line String).

```
val inputLine = "foo, bar, bar, foo".split(", ").toList
```

That works.  But I want to pass multiple lines into my function.

```
val inputList = List("""foo, bar, bar, foo, 
bar, foo, foo, bar,
foo, bar, bar, foo""")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... first of all, lets understand few things so that you can explain your question more clearly.

```
// This is a single-line string
val singleLineString = "I am a single line string"

// This is a multi-line string
val multiLineString = """I am a
multiline
string"""

// This is a List of Strings
val list1 = List("string1", "string2")

// List just looks at String... it does not care whether the strings are mutli-line or single-line
val list2 = List(singleLineString, multiLineString)
```

Now... if you have a multi-line String,

```
val inputMultiLineString = """blah1, blah2, blah3, blah4, 
blah5, blah6, blah7, blah8,
blah9, blah10, blah11, blah12"""
```

And you want to break each of these lines into words while keeping them separate.

```
val yourSeparatedLines = inputMultiLineString
  .split("\n")
  .map(line => line.split(",").map(word => word.trim).toList)  
  .toList

// yourSeparatedLines: List[List[String]] = List(List(blah1, blah2, blah3, blah4), List(blah5, blah6, blah7, blah8), List(blah9, blah10, blah11, blah12))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val inputList = """foo, bar, bar, foo, 
bar, foo, foo, bar,
foo, bar, bar, foo""".split(",\\s*").toList

println(inputList)
```

The `,\s*` regex means "comma and then 0 or more spaces" where space is a [whitespace character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (includes \r \n and space...).